# Python - Starting two threads - Thread (t2) name error

Tags: python, multithreading, class

This simple example seems to work fine but when I implement this same code in a only slightly more complicated codebase I get a error `NameError: name 't2' is not defined` when `add` is called from `class QuoteReport` using `t2.add(key[0], key[1])`.  Is the way I am starting the two threads in `main` okay?  Though this code seems to work is there anything here that is not good form?  The only differnce I see from my simplified example and the one that fails is QueueReport and CallReport are in a seperate file from the main file.  But I know the import is working because 1)if I change the code to `t2 = CallReport_badname()` it fails calls is cant find that class 2)I run some logging from the `run` method of `CallReport` and it does print to log.  I would assume once those classes are imported I would call it as `t2`?  is there anthing speical I should be doing when the instance of one class calls an instance of another class?

```
from threading import * 
import time

class QueueReport(Thread):
  def __init__(self):
    Thread.__init__(self)
    self.reports_to_call = {}

  def add(self, user, report):
    self.reports_to_call.update({(user, report): None})
    print("Added Value - Queue Report")
    print(len(self.reports_to_call))

  def run(self):
    print("Running - que\n")
    time.sleep(10)

    while True:
        for key in self.reports_to_call:
            print(key)
            print("about to add to t2")
            t2.add(key[0], key[1])
        time.sleep(120)

class CallReport(Thread):
  def __init__(self):
    Thread.__init__(self)
    self.reports_called = {}

  def add(self, user, report):
    self.reports_called.update({(user, report): None})
    print("Added Value to reports called")
    print("len2", len(self.reports_called))


   def run(self):
    print("Running - Call\n")
    time.sleep(10)

    while True:
        for key in self.reports_called:
            print("key from running", key)
            #do something with this key and delete if succcessful
        print("Call Report done- waiting to loop")
        time.sleep(20)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  t1 = QueueReport()
  thread = Thread(target=t1.run)
  thread.start()

  t2 = CallReport()
  thread2 = Thread(target=t2.run)
  thread2.start()


t1.add("bob", "report2r")
time.sleep(1)
t1.add("tom", "report2")
time.sleep(1)
t1.add("harry", "report3")
time.sleep(15) # add new after first loop
t1.add("john", "report4")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there will be a difference if you move the logic into different files. t1 and t2 are declared in `main` method which makes them global variables and thus can be accessible by both the classes. If they are in different files you have to pass them around to access.

```
from threading import *
import time

class QueueReport(Thread):
  def __init__(self, call_report_thread):
    Thread.__init__(self)
    self.reports_to_call = {}
    self.call_report_thread = call_report_thread
  def run(self):
    print("Running - que\n")
    time.sleep(10)

    while True:
        for key in self.reports_to_call:
            print(key)
            print("about to add to t2")
            self.call_report_thread.add(key[0], key[1])
        time.sleep(120)

class CallReport(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.reports_called = {}

    def add(self, user, report):
        self.reports_called.update({(user, report): None})
        print("Added Value to reports called")
        print("len2", len(self.reports_called))


    def run(self):
        print("Running - Call\n")
        time.sleep(10)

        while True:
            for key in self.reports_called:
             print("key from running", key)
            #do something with this key and delete if succcessful
            print("Call Report done- waiting to loop")
            time.sleep(20)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  t2 = CallReport()
  t2.start()

  t1 = QueueReport(t2)
  t1.start()
```

I am assuming here that which thread starts first won't matter.

Comment: Thanks.. But I dont totally follow your answer.  if t1 and t2 are declared in main(which they are) and they are gobal variables (which I agree) and can be access by both classes why is the second class not finiding it. 

To add more clarity both classes are in a second file called reports which I import sucessfully.  Once inported isnt that class the same as if it in the main file. (main file not main method).   

It seems(if I understand your solution correctly) are you creating a new callreport thread for every instance of the QueueReport thread?

Comment: You are *creating* the thread in one file and *accessing* it in other file, that's the problem here. So, let's say you have one file with the code of `main()` and other file which contains both the classes, the first file have a global variable `t2` but the other file  can't access it. I am not creating a new callreport thread, I just want to pass it to QueueReport thread.

Comment: ok.. this starting to make sense.  I see the args=(t2,) ties the threads together.  Is it correct that t2 this is then passed in to QueueReport as call_report_thread?

Comment: Very intersting.. with arg=(t2,) I get a error.     t1 = QueueReport()
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'call_report_thread'

the passing of args=(t2,) doesnt seem to fill the call_report_thread argument. 

I put the code in an online ide as well to double check
https://repl.it/@RichZellmer/ThreadExample

Comment: @personalt fixed the code, see the edited answer. 1. There is no need for `thread1` and `thread2` variable as you are extending from `Thread`. When the `start()` gets called the `run()` gets called. 2.  Pass `t2` as an argument to `QueueReport` when it gets instantiated.

Comment: This seems to be the correct answer.  I will take more detailed look when I get home from work and then mark this as correct answer ..  Thank you

Comment: this did work... marked your answer as correct.. thanks for help