# Python - Missing Positional Argument when setting up threading. Arguments are defined

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

In this code I am trying to set up two threads, where an instance of QueueReport (t1) will call an instance of CallReport(t2). I am getting a missing positonal argument error when adding the argument was the exact change I was attempting to make. 
 Error I get is `t1 = QueueReport() TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'call_report_thread'`

In order to link the threads I made two lines of changes.  In `main` I added the `t2` arg   `thread = Thread(target=t1.run, args=(t2,)) # notice here`.  In the init of `class QueueReport` I added the argumement `def __init__(self, call_report_thread)`.

I did put a version of this code in python ide at - https://repl.it/@RichZellmer/thread-arg if anyone wants to dig in to it.

```
from threading import *
import time

class QueueReport(Thread):
  def __init__(self, call_report_thread):  # notice - added call_report_thread
    Thread.__init__(self)
    self.reports_to_call = {}
    self.call_report_thread = call_report_thread

   def add(self, user, report):
     self.reports_to_call.update({(user, report): None})
     print("Added Value - Queue Report")

   def run(self):
       print("Running - que\n")
       time.sleep(10)
       while True:
          for key in self.reports_to_call:
             print(key)
             print("about to add to t2")
             self.call_report_thread.add(key[0], key[1])
             time.sleep(120)

class CallReport(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
       Thread.__init__(self)
       self.reports_called = {}

    def run(self):
        print("Do stuff with value in new dict")
        time.sleep(10)

   def add(self, user, report):    
       print("add value to new dict")  


if __name__ == '__main__':
   t2 = CallReport()
   thread2 = Thread(target=t2.run)
   thread2.start()

   t1 = QueueReport()
   thread = Thread(target=t1.run, args=(t2,)) # notice here
   thread.start()

   t1.add("bob", "report2r")
   time.sleep(1)
   t1.add("tom", "report2")
   time.sleep(1)
   t1.add("harry", "report3")
```

Comment: why are you inheriting from `Thread` in the first place?

Comment: The point of overriding `run` is so that you don't have to specify a target when you create the thread; the `Thread`'s default target is its `run` method.

Comment: Also, why is `QueueReport` creating a new `Thread` object when it runs? If that's really what you want to do, pass `t2` as an argument to `QueueReport`, and call `self.call_report_thread` explicitly from `QueueReport.run`, dropping the `args` argument from `Thread`. (`t1.run` doesn't define any parameters, so specifying `args` doesn't make sense.)

Comment: @chepner - I got here from a previous question.   In that question I was getting errors when calling t2.add from anstance of t1.    I tried to implement the suggesiton in that answer. 

 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59092542/python-starting-two-threads-thread-t2-name-error/59092685?noredirect=1#comment104420414_59092685

Comment: @chepner - I edited the code in my question to give some more context as well